# prefix param rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, prefix

I'm using rails3 and I want to have a route prefix like below:

I have the following in my routes:

```
require 'resque/server'

Woofound::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "/:my_param" do
    resource :users
  end
end
```

And then I have the following in my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter :check_param

   private
   def check_param
     unless Myobject.find_by_param(param[:my_param])
       raise "You must add this param"
     end
   end
end
```

And then in my routes I want to have be able to access the user_path(@user) without having to do

```
user_path(:param_for_route_name_spacing, @user)
```

If you need more clarity let me know.

And in short I want to have a parameterized prefix for my route with the parameter automatically being passed back into the parameterized namespace without having to add it as the first argument to am object path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def user_path(user)
    super(:param_for_route_name_spacing, user)
  end
end
```

Comment: OK, your routes file should have `resources :users` not `resource :users` and call `helper_method :user_path` in the controller.

Comment: I accidentally put an :as => :something_else in my route

Your fix is perfect, thank you very much

Comment: I ended up using `default_url_options`
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default-url-options